# Fetching image using picasso library in android app

Tags: android, imageview, picasso, dynamic-ui

I am developing an android app and it is static now. To make it dynamic, i am thinking to fetch images using picasso library. But it is not showing the image of the url. Here is my code given below -

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Picasso.with(this)
            .load("http://s12.postimg.org/k07c5mzil/images_1.jpg")
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(imageView);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have given internet permission in android.manifest.

And also the dependency for picasso library -

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

But still i am not able to see the image of the url.
Please help me...

Comment: try setting a size to the imageview, or match_parent, it could be that it just not gets drawn (picasso does not resize your view)

Comment: can i do in this way? uploading image to some free image hosting website and using url of that image?

Comment: URL is probably not correct too... Avoid redirects

Comment: That url is not an image..

Comment: yup @VizGhar and kientux... I have changed the image url. Now please cross check my code and i request you for some solution.

Comment: have you tried @bleeding182 recommendation? set ImageView width and height. wrap_content sets it to 0dp probably

Comment: For testing purposes to 64x64 dp, just to see it... and also
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in Manifest

Answer (score 1):

```
Picasso.with(this)
        .load("http://s12.postimg.org/k07c5mzil/images_1.jpg")
        .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .into(imageView);
```

Will load **image** into **`imageView`** from given **URL**.

- image - Have to be image (not some redirects or so)
- imageView - It have to be visible with non zero dimensions (specify width and height)
- URL - you have to have connection to internet, therefor you have to declare it in manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Can you recommend me some portal for image storage so that i can use for this purpose? is it possible to upload in the server to which i have hosted my app and use the link of that image?

Comment: I have somename.xml in the db which is loading into ImageView via Picasso but OnBitmapFailed() is called for every Image.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code and change as following 
I have tested and it's working perfectly fine.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewOfurl);
    Context context = imageView.getContext();
    String url = "http://yaitisme.com/images/getImage.jpg";



    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .resize(50,50)
            .into(imageView);
```

You can replace names according to your program.

The reason of your problem might be the size, so you can resize it.
also do wrap content in both width and height of imageview.
Internet permission as well. 
hope it helps!